# The destination component does not have any available inputs for use in creating a path

Tags: ssis

[image]I'm working with legacy tsql code that outputs to txt files.
For security reasons, I'm replacing these outputs with SSIS packages.
I've gotten most of them to work, but one particular one gives me the following error:

### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

Cannot create connector.
The destination component does not have any available inputs for use in creating a path.

The data flow itself is very simple. OLE DB Source runs an SQL command, then outputs to a flatfile source that points to an existing txtfile that was created by the TSQL.

Anyone know what the error means in regards to the available inputs?

Comment: Post a screenshot of your data flow, if you would

Comment: Oh, wait. Does it really go `OLE DB Source` to `Flat File Source`

Comment: Is the source connected to the destination?

Answer (score 7):

Your SSIS toolbox is divided into 3 general groupings (pre 2012/2014)

- Sources
- Transformations
- Destinations

A source has 1 to N output paths. Nothing can feed *into* a source. Things can only consume what a Source emits.

A Transformation does not generate<sup>*</sup> rows, it accepts rows from an upstream provider (either a Source or another Transformation). A Transformation has 1 to N output paths.

A Destination is the terminus for data. I'm not aware of any destinations that accept more than one input. It has one optional output path, Error.

Your problem, therefore, is that you are trying to route data into a Source. Change that to a `Flat File Destination`.

Comment: Yup. You know it's a long day when you're confusing source and destination....
Thanks!

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, @yoelbenyossef, I just made the same mistake almost 4 years later.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the `Flat File Source` with a `Flat File Destination` task. Click on the `RowCount` task and drag the green arrow to the new destination.

Comment: That's what I've done in the past.
This time when I do, I get the SSIS error telling me that there are no available inputs.